# How to deal with Many to Many database in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, many-to-many

I am working on a ASP.Net Web API and I have been bangin my head to the wall but I had no luck so far with the many to many relationship.
I am working on a MVC project

I have 3 tables classes as you can see below:

```
 [Table("Emails")]
    public class Email
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Reports")]
    public class Report
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 [Table("ReportsAndEmails")]
    public class ReportAndEmail
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int EmailID { get; set; }

        public int ReportID { get; set; }
    }
```

On table ReporsAndEmails, I have two foreign keys, Id in Email table is the foreign key for EmailID and Id in Report is the foreign Key for ReportID. Everything works as I expect. But I want to be able is, I want to show all the records in ReportAndEmail table to the user, but instead of showing EmailID, match the id in Email table and show the EmailAddress and the same way for the ReportID. I want o match the reportID with he Report table's ID and show the Name instead.

I know I can hack the code to show that in the client part by loading all the tables and matching data, but I know that approach is so silly. but I am making an API web project, so I want to deal with that in the server side rather than the client side. My question is, what is the best way of dealing with this issue? What should I really do ? Any comment on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Linq join.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b (search for "join" on the page) has the following example, but you need to join 3 tables in a similar way.

```
public void Linq102() 
{ 

string[] categories = new string[]{  
    "Beverages",   
    "Condiments",   
    "Vegetables",   
    "Dairy Products",   
    "Seafood" };  

List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

var q = 
    from c in categories 
    join p in products on c equals p.Category 
    select new { Category = c, p.ProductName }; 

foreach (var v in q) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(v.ProductName + ": " + v.Category);  
} 
}
```